# What is an efficient method to cancel multiple AsyncTask callbacks that will return in the future if a condition is met midway?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, time-series

I have a pretty standard static class extending `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response<String>>{

    // Some members, including a listener

    public MyAsyncTask( // some params ){
        // Init
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // some background work

        return response;  // e.g., a Response<T> object as found in Retrofit

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response<String> response) {
        // Send result params to a listener for further processing
        listener.onMyAsyncTaskResult( //params );
    }

}
```

A main method generates time-series data. The main method calls `MyAsyncTask` for each data point as and when it is generated by the main method. `MyAsyncTask` handles some network calls (e.g. using Retrofit) and other async operations that are generated for each element in the time-series. State information is to be maintained corresponding to each data point in the time-series, before and after `MyAsyncTask` returns.

The main method may terminate either automatically or by user input, such that the network responses for some past data in the time-series are still pending.

The main method displays a final state to the user after it is terminated. Ideally, I would like to wait for all the network responses, using which the final state may be displayed on a "best-effort" basis. But if a `waitingThreshold` is crossed, I would like to terminate the pending callbacks, since waiting too much after having completed an action doesn't generally make for good UX. This is **the trade-off** here.

Further, after the main method is terminated, it can be relaunched either automatically or by user input, in which case, the callbacks from the previous instance of the main method are no longer required. Also, for example, any additional background work (such as database writes) that happens in the callbacks become unnecessary because the final state of the previous instance of the main method has already been set.

The main method and callbacks run inside a `Service`.

---

One way to do this is to simply track the state of the main method globally, such as using `boolean isMainMethodTerminated`, and ignore the response in the callback if it has been terminated.

```
isMainMethodTerminated = false;
if(time > waitingThreshold){
    // Terminate the main time-series method
    isMainMethodTerminated = true;
}

...

@Override
public void onMyAsyncTaskResult( //params ){
    if(!isMainMethodTerminated){
        // continue using the callback
    }
}
```

Using this method, the callbacks will still keep happening, but we just side-step the work inside the callback.

Is it better to instead call `.cancel()` on each instance of the pending `MyAsyncTask`s?

---

While I can use the above interception method using `isMainMethodTerminated`, **it doesn't solve the problem very neatly**.

What would be the efficient method(s) to handle **the trade-off**?

Comment: P.S.: I could also use an `Executor` / `ExecutorService` to run a custom `Runnable` with an attached callback, instead of using an `AsyncTask`. I've heard not-so-good things about `AsyncTask` in general.

Comment: i suppose the real question would be why are you still using async tasks, they are deprecated. something like rxjava could even potentially make something like this a lot simpler

Comment: Presently, the app targets API level 29. `AsyncTask` is deprecated starting Android 11. I will be reworking the code, but at a later time.

Also, as I mentioned above, I am open to using other options. Would you be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Also, although I'm not using the reactive approach (RxJava), I am using the publish-subscribe approach (EventBus) wherever necessary. My present task is being handled rather easily using this. But I can imagine scenarios where this task would become more complex, making it necessary to use something like RxJava in the future.

Comment: not really here to give answers at the moment, just hanging out between app builds :) just sounded from your title that you could benefit from rxjava, as it sounded like you were chaining operations. considering that async tasks are deprecated, meaning there are better ways of doing something, thought it was worth suggesting

Comment: Haha, thanks anyways. I'll look into whether RxJava will make the job easier.